# flot chart not updating with ajax returned data

Tags: jquery, ajax, flot

I am working on flot chart.here's the code which is not working when i assign the value from ajax returned data ..(**code not working**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  get_data();
});
function get_data() { 
  var options = { 
    lines: {show: true}, 
    points: {show: true}, 
    legend: {show: true, backgroundColor: "#fff", noColumns: 4, 
                position: "nw"}, 
    yaxis: { min: 0 }, 
    xaxis: { tickDecimals: 0 }, 
    grid: {color:"#CCCCCC", backgroundColor: "#fffaff"} 
  }; 
var start_date="September 14, 2014";
var user_group="USG0001";
var start_time=0;
var end_time=1200;
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'....'}).done(function(result){

      { 
        plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), result, options); 
      } 
  }); 
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

Instead of passing the result of ajax data,if i assign it directly, it works:(**working code**)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
  get_data();
});
function get_data() { 
  var options = { 
    lines: {show: true}, 
    points: {show: true}, 
    legend: {show: true, backgroundColor: "#fff", noColumns: 4, 
                position: "nw"}, 
    yaxis: { min: 0 }, 
    xaxis: { tickDecimals: 0 }, 
    grid: {color:"#CCCCCC", backgroundColor: "#fffaff"} 
  }; 
var start_date="September 14, 2014";
var user_group="USG0001";
var start_time=0;
var end_time=1200;
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'.....'}).done(function(result){

      { 
        result=[{"label":"meter1","data":[[0,0],[1,194],[2,223],[3,182],[4,201],[5,213],[6,206],[7,182],[8,266],[9,246],[10,238],[11,248],[12,210]]},{"label":1,"data":[[0,0],[1,98],[2,97],[3,100],[4,96],[5,94],[6,100],[7,94],[8,95],[9,99],[10,104],[11,98],[12,99]]},{"label":2,"data":[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,1],[6,12],[7,13],[8,35],[9,43],[10,44],[11,49],[12,43]]},{"label":3,"data":[[0,0],[1,7],[2,6],[3,7],[4,6],[5,7],[6,7],[7,6],[8,44],[9,59],[10,56],[11,46],[12,32]]},{"label":4,"data":[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,7],[9,25],[10,24],[11,17],[12,20]]},{"label":5,"data":[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,1],[10,1],[11,23],[12,22]]},{"label":6,"data":[[0,0],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2],[7,3],[8,13],[9,15],[10,16],[11,18],[12,19]]},{"label":7,"data":[[0,0],[1,0],[2,1],[3,0],[4,0],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1],[8,50],[9,106],[10,133],[11,135],[12,112]]},];
        plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), result, options); 
      } 
  }); 
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

why it's not working if i use the value directly from ajax returned data,any help ?

ps:the data returned from the ajax call is same as that of the value assigned in the working case.

Comment: Check console for error. In `$.ajax` is `dataType: 'json'` ?

Comment: There is no error in console @Krzysiek

Comment: can you check if `console.log(result)` give you valid object? Not string for instance...

Comment: i checked console.log(typeof(result))..it is giving me a string @Krzysiek

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to options of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to define plot in ready method. and after ajax call you need to setData as below. Draw the plot again. Refer following code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var data = [];
     var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options); // define   options
   $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'.....'}).done(function(result){
  { 
    plot.setData([{data:result}]);
    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.draw();
   }
});
```